# How to disable or remove kopete?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, kopete

I don't like kopete to start when Kde 4.7 starts. But I don't find the way to disable it - it's not to find within the startup apps or services. When I try to uninstall the package "kdenetwork" gets removed also. But this package sounds important ...

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the desktop related packages don't change very often, you won't have any side effects. You can safely remove kopete. kdenetwork is just the group package for the network software collection. It is like kubuntu-desktop, linux-image-generic.

[kdenetwork filelist](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/all/kdenetwork/filelist)

Comment: thx a lot! ... removed it, feelin better now! :-), p.